# PHP scripts in Stack Snippets

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Now I don't know PHP or how exactly it fits into HTML, but I had an idea that you could run a PHP script in a Stack Snippet. Is this true, and if so could you give some examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is impossible. PHP is server-side, but snippets are client-side.

Comment: You could theoretically add support for server-side snippets, but I don't even want to think about that security disaster.

Comment: There are services like http://repl.it/ that support languages like PHP, so I assume it wouldn't be impossible to make it secure.

Comment: repl.it tends to disable entire imports or groups of functions, (maybe for security?). One example is you cannot `import json` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, if somebody added a PHP-to-Javascript converter like the other converters shown [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/), it could be possible. It would most likely be only a partial solution capable of only a subset of PHP's features, if ever implemented, since some wouldn't be possible.